# How can I validate the boolean?

Tags: json, spring, validation

```
    Response testEndpoint(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @RequestBody @Valid @NotNull(message = "not null") boolean consent);
```

I have the above endpoint which just expects a boolean value in the json.
If it is null it gives the validation error. If I input 'true' or 'false' then it works, but if I enter something like "hello" it gives:

```
"message": "Unable to parse JSON",
"errors": []
```

How can I give a suitable error message against erroneous input?
Is it ok to just accept true/false here or should I use a proper structure?

Comment: A primitive cannot be null so a `@NotNull` check is pretty much useless. Also a valid that cannot be converted to a boolean (like your `hello`) will indeed throw an error only true/false 0/1 etc. can be converted.

Comment: You must use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` in this case, as long as parsing illegal values (not "true" or "false") will cause NullPointerException when `boolean` is a target class